# OpenVAS Feed Status: How to check the automatic synchronization?

Tags: openvas

I've just installed OpenVAS ... however when I checked on Feed Status, I found that OpenVAS CERT Feed is too old as shown in the screenshot below.

> **Too old (14 days)** - Please check the automatic synchronization of your system

The solution suggested was to check automatic synchronization in the system. Unfortunately I was not sure how to do that.

I've searched around but couldn't find similar problem. So I guess posting the question here might be helpful.

OpenVAS CERT Feed Status: Please check the automatic synchronization of your system

[image: OpenVAS CERT Feed Status: Please check the automatic synchronization of your system]

Answer (score 2):

To get updated content from the feeds you need to run the following scripts (in this order) on a daily base via e.g. cron:

greenbone-nvt-sync

greenbone-scapdata-sync

greenbone-certdata-sync

If there is any issue during the sync the scripts should give you additional info.

Comment: I would add that you typically will need to prefix all of those with 'sudo'. Not doing so will result in the scripting going through everything... but with 'permission denied'.

Comment: Please note the added info about not running the scripts with sudo/root privileges in https://serverfault.com/a/992526/464580.

Answer (score 2):

As of November 2019, you are not permitted to run the *-sync scripts as 'root'.

I installed openvas on a Kali system and found that I had some changes to make.  Openvas must be installed as 'root' and openvas-setup is also supposed to be run as 'root'.  But at the end of the process, there are artifacts that have root ownership and read-only attributes for everyone else which get in the way of the *-sync scripts running.

Until they sort out the installation procedures and instructions, I would recommend doing the following (after install and openvas-setup).

1. sudo adduser openvas
2. sudo chown -R openvas: /var/lib/openvas
3. sudo chown -R openvas: /var/log/openvas
4. Run the scripts in the answer above
5. Better yet, make a cron job that does it (as openvas)

No need to do the chown for both the users and groups when you can do it in a single command.

Answer (score 0):

I still get this issue with the certdata which is of vital importance to ongoing scanning operations. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbaT2.png)

root@20c9a5c57c4d:/# greenbone-scapdata-sync
rsync: getaddrinfo:  873: No address associated with hostname
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(128) [Receiver=3.1.1]